# Create JavaScript array of function pointer, without calling it

Tags: javascript, json

I have the code below. I would like to have an array (buttons) with a single element pointing to the a function (closeFlag).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var closeFlag = new function() {
        alert('Clicked');
    }
    var buttons = {
        'OK': closeFlag
    }
</script>
```

However, when loading the page the alert immediately pops up. When the array is constructed, instead of using it as a pointer, JavaScript calls my function.
Why? What mistake, misconception do I have?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `new` keyword, you will not need it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var closeFlag = function() {
    alert('Clicked');
  }
  var buttons = {
    'OK': closeFlag
  }
</script>
```

What's happening in your code is that it's constructing the anonymous function then assigning the result of it (`this`) to `closeFlag`.

Comment: Wow, I really missed on that.

Comment: The result of the construction of the anonymous function isn't `undefined`, is a newly created object (the `this` value inside the constructor function is returned implicitly)